# Javascript not accessible from inside Angular ui-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a main template (index.html) with an Angular ui-view. Inside this main template I import a bunch of Javascript files. I expect these files to be available to the content inside the html templates that will be loaded inside the ui-view, but the JS functions are seemingly inaccessible.

**/sample-app/index.html:**

```
<html ng-app="otr">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- JS imports -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts -->
    <script src="/sample-app/js/login.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular app scripts -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/authentication.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/flash.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app/common/cases-model.js"></script>

    <script src="app/home/home.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app/login/login.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app/register/register.controller.js"></script>        

</body>
</html>
```

**/sample-app/js/login.js**

```
$(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        console.log('Inside login.js REGISTER');
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

**/sample-app/app/app.js:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('otr', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngCookies',
        'ui.router',
    ])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('otr', {
                url: '',
                abstract: true
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                controller: 'LoginController as vm',
                templateUrl: 'app/login/login.view.html'
            })
            .state('register', {
                url: '/register',
                controller: 'RegisterController as vm',
                templateUrl: 'app/register/register.view.html'
            })
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                controller: 'HomeController as vm',
                templateUrl: 'pages/home2.view.html'
            })
        ;

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }

    function run($rootScope, $location, $cookies, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookies.get('globals') || {};

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }

})();
```

- The ui-view content loads just fine, but without the JS functions being called.
- If I copy/paste the  content directly into index.html, everything works as expected
- If I place the JS import inside the partial template, that works as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post more detail about what you have inside of app.js?  I may be assuming things about your code that I should not.

Comment: Instead of writing a bunch of jQuery to do your animations, use ng-animate. It will make your life easier and de-speghetti some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on trying to get the JavaScript to load and the ui-view to recognize it. I ultimately solved this by creating an Angular directive that duplicated the function of the JavaScript.

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('otr')
    .directive('loginForm', loginFormDirective)
    .directive('registerForm', registerFormDirective)
;

function loginFormDirective() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('click', function() {
            console.log('element: ', element[0].id);
            console.log('attributes: ', attrs);

            $('#' + attrs.loginForm).delay(100).fadeIn(100);
            $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
            $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + element[0].id).addClass('active');
        })
    }
}

function registerFormDirective() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('click', function() {
            $('#' + attrs.registerForm).delay(100).fadeIn(100);
            $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
            $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + element[0].id).addClass('active');
        })
    }
}
```

My view now has the following code snippet:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link" login-form="login-form">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" id="register-form-link" register-form="register-form">Register</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks to all of you who took the time to read my question and post answers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access stuff outside the , try to create a controller, something like this,

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ui-view></div>
      <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: how can this would solve the issue of js file loading

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your project structure it's hard to know for sure, but I suspect that you need to refer to your javascript files using absolute paths rather than relative paths.

EG:

```
<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
```

I say this because most AngularJS projects store their views in a sub-folder, and when the template gets loaded the relative paths become invalid because they are relative to the root of the project/index.html file and not the active view.

Comment: I just tried that, but no luck. I've tried full path as well as relative path. Neither seem to work.

Comment: Are you testing locally or from a web server? If it's local, you can tell it's local if the URL in the browser starts with file:,then try swapping back to relative paths and ensure that your project is structured in such a way as the paths are valid for the index and views.

Also, if you bring up the developer's console in your browser, is it providing any clues?

Comment: I went back to using relative paths. I'm running this on a local server (i.e. http://localhost:63342/...). The Developer Console does not complain about anything and doesn't give me any clues as to what might be wrong. If i give it the wrong path for the JS file though, it does complain, so I know it finds the file.

Comment: When you put the code into the main file and it works, do you include all of it verbatim, or do you change any of it. Also, where do you place it? Header or end of body?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have a statement somewhere in `app.js` that looks like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []);
```

You will need to manually bootstrap your application.  If you have any `ng-app=` markup in your html, remove it -- make sure `app.js` is the very last script, and add the following to the end of `app.js`:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
});
```

If you didn't have `ng-app` in your markup, then you wouldn't have seen anything anyway, as `ng-app` is the key that tells angular where it should integrate with your page.  And `ng-app` should not be applied until all of the scripts are loaded.

But even if you had it, it still would have given you an error that the directive is not defined.  The reason is that angular.js will begin executing as soon as it is loaded.  But the code you've written which attaches the directive to your module has not gotten a chance to execute.  Very specifically, it means that there is not yet a directive called 'ui-view' defined in your application.

The reason angular code seems to just work when you put it into `index.html` is that angular is kind enough to wait for the DOM to be ready before actually trying to hook up components, and that means that any inline scripts have already gotten a chance to execute.

Keep this bootstrapping trick in your bag, as you'll be using it often.

Comment: OP already stated that the view loads...so why all the explanation about `ng-app` and bootstrapping? If OP

Comment: If the javascript is unavailable, then it has not loaded -- and most likely for the reasons I've described.  `ui-view` is almost certainly a directive taken from `angular-ui-router`, so it's not bundled with the OP's code.  But I do appreciate your concern for the OP.

Comment: I think you misread question. Yes needs ui-roter but how would OP be seeing views rendered inside `ui-view` if they hadn;t already included as dependency? Issue is about the js that's in script tags inside those views

Comment: I appreciate your interest.  Soon after submitting this answer, I left a message with the OP to ask for clarification and additional code samples -- in the event I was making bad assumptions.  It's not that I don't trust your interpretation, but I'm going to wait for the OP to respond.  There is simply not enough information provided in the question for us to have an educated back-and-forth.  ;-)

Comment: @MichaelHays I tried this approach but it didn't solve my problem. It works just the same whether I use the trick above or leave the ng-app attribute in place. 

I've added more code above to eliminate assumptions. My issue is not getting my partial templates to load inside the <ui-view> but rather that the markup inside the partial templates don't have access to the JS imported in index.html. If I instead place the <script> inside the partial template, it works as expected.

Comment: @AlexG -- Your example shows app.js loading before the other scripts.  Once again, it has to be the last script.  And the last line of the last script has to be the bootstrap.  Since it's not the last script (did I tell you it has to be the last script?), the other javascript will not have loaded.  It works when you put the script in the partial template because you are, in effect, making your own script the last script to be loaded.  To prove it to yourself, write a `console.log` into each of your scripts and inside your directive so that you can see the order that things are happening.

Comment: But, thank you for the clarification -- usually people load all of their third party libraries before their own.  So that was a bad assumption on my part that you would have done that.  Once you re-order your scripts so that yours is last, you'll hopefully find my answer makes more sense.

Comment: @MichaelHays Thanks for checking back in. Really appreciate your help. I tried putting app.js as the last script, but if I do that, my other angular scripts (controllers, services, etc.) complain that the module 'otr' is not loaded.

Each controller starts with the line: 

    angular.module('otr')
               .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

In any case, I tried putting these Angular scripts at the bottom, but with no success.

Comment: What I also tried is to put the line you recommended in its own script and load that last. No success with that either.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the app name using ng-app, then associate a controller with an element in the HTML. I would suggest [this tutorial](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) because you are missing few of the basics.

You need to do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp" lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.foo = function(){};
        this.foo2 = function(){};
    })
})();
```

Comment: I've clarified the question further. I should have made it clear that I do already have ng-app specified and controllers hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a super late response, but I ran into this same exact issue myself. I have solved this by including the external js libraries before including Angular and Angular UI Router.

Just like the OP, my project consisted of an index.html as well as a ui-view. The partials load into the ui-view properly, but the external js libraries do not take effect inside the partial via ui-view. If the contents from the partial are placed into the index.html, everything works perfectly.

**Scripts changed from**

```
<!-- AngularJS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/components.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Custom JS Libries -->
<script src="dist/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Scripts changed to**

```
<!-- Custom JS Libries -->
<script src="dist/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- AngularJS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/components.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Final Outcome and working**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" data-config='{"style": "calico"}'>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/all.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">

    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- Custom JS Libries -->
    <script src="dist/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/components.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i get it solved.

1. In your app.js, create is on controller,
2. add the controller name to ur index body
3. the convert the template js to a method.
4. then create a scope method in your app.js controller.
5. In the scope method, call the template js method
6. Inside the ui-view html template or ur dashboard, use ng-init to call the scope method of your app.js controller using

Here is the working example:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="zeusWeb" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="zeusWeb" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="zeusWeb" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="zeusWeb" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Screening Manager</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="education, institution, management, portal,screening,application">
  <meta name="description" content="education, institution, management, portal,screening,application">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  <meta name="author" content="K-Devs System Solutions">
  <meta name="owner" content="Kazeem Olanipekun">
  <meta name="verified by" content="K-Devs System Solutions">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noodp">
  <meta name="google" content="translate">
  <meta name="revisit-after" content="1 month">
  <!-- build:css css/main.css-->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/iCheck/skins/flat/blue.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/nprogress/nprogress.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/switchery/dist/switchery.css" />
  <!--endbower-->
  <!--custom:css-->
  <link href="template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <!-- endcustom  css-->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/screening.ico" type='image/x-icon'/>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/screening.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="zeusWebCtrl" class="nav-md footer_fixed">
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <data ui-view ng-cloak></data>

  <!-- build:js js/vendors.js-->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/iCheck/icheck.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/transitionize/dist/transitionize.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/switchery/dist/switchery.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->


  <!-- build:js js/main.js-->
  <!-- code inclusion-->
  <script src="template.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <!--end inclusion -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

</body>
</html>
```

here is the app.js

```
'use strict';
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var zeusWeb=angular.module('zeusWeb', ['ui.router', 'angular-loading-bar','dashboard']);
zeusWeb.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','cfpLoadingBarProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,cfpLoadingBarProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  /**
   *   State for the very first page of the app. This is the home page .
   */
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
  });
/*
  $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
        url:'/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
        controllerAs:'vm'
  });*/

/*
  $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
    views:{
      'body':{
        url:'/embed',
        templateUrl: 'view1/embed.html',
        controller: 'embed',
        controllerAs:'vm'
      }
    }
  });*/

}]);
zeusWeb.controller('zeusWebCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = "Testing";
  $scope.appTemplate=function () {
  template();
  };

}]);
```

here is the embed ui-view dashboard.html

```
<div  class="container body">
    <div class="main_container">
        <!--sidebar-->
        <section  data-ng-include="'views/dashboard/sidebar-nav.html'" data-ng-controller="sideBarCtrl as vm"></section>
        <!--sidebar-->

        <!-- top navigation -->
        <section  data-ng-include="'views/dashboard/header.html'"></section>
        <!-- /top navigation -->

        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main" ui-view="body">
            hey
          <!--  <script>template();</script>-->
        </div>
        <!-- /page content -->
        <!--footer-->
        <section  data-ng-include="'views/dashboard/footer.html'"></section>
        <!--footer-->
    </div>
</div>
<div data-ng-init="$parent.appTemplate()"></div>
```

Please note that if you are having an asynchronous inject sidebars html based on roles. make sure you have a default sidebar html that will put this  insted of the dashboard and also make sure that the default sidebar will be loaded last after all other sidebars has loaded successfully.

in my case, here is a sample example of the sidebars.

school admin html sidebar

```
<div  class="menu_section">
    <h3>Live On</h3>
    <ul class="nav side-menu">
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Additional Pages <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="e_commerce.html">E-commerce</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="project_detail.html">Project Detail</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Extras <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="page_403.html">403 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="page_404.html">404 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="page_500.html">500 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="plain_page.html">Plain Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html">Login Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing_tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Multilevel Menu <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="#level1_1">Level One</a>
                <li><a>Level One<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li class="sub_menu"><a href="level2.html">Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#level2_1">Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#level2_2">Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#level1_2">Level One</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Landing Page <span class="label label-success pull-right">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then, let assume that is the last sidebar of the user, then you then call the default sidebar to call the function

default sidebar html

```
<div data-ng-init="$parent.appTemplate()"></div>`enter code here
```

---