# angular javascript won't apply to ui-view inserted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, uiview

When I paste the code from main.html to index.html, the javascript code works fine,  the click function will trigger the ripple effect.

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/ripple-click-effect-google-material-design>

But when I extract the code to main.html, and inserted it through ui-view,  the content get inserted to index.html, but the javascript code doesn't work anymore.  it gets loaded, but the function just won't apply to the ul li a element.

[Javascript not accessible from inside Angular ui-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995949/javascript-not-accessible-from-inside-angular-ui-view)

I think this post asked the same question, it is not solved.  a custom directive does solve the problem,  but you cant just use directives to mimic the functionality of ui router

Truly appreciate any help! thanks.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <base href="/">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="blog">

    <div ui-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controller/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controller/main.controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/scripts/ripple.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('blog', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

main.js

```
    'use strict';

    angular.module('blog')
      .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          });
      });
```

app/views/main.html

```
  <div id="blogHeader" class = "container">
    <div class="jumbotron">

    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Study note</a></li>
    </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

ripple.js

```
//jQuery time
var parent, ink, d, x, y;
$("ul li a").click(function(e){
    parent = $(this).parent();
    //create .ink element if it doesn't exist
    if(parent.find(".ink").length == 0)
        parent.prepend("<span class='ink'></span>");

    ink = parent.find(".ink");
    //incase of quick double clicks stop the previous animation
    ink.removeClass("animate");

    //set size of .ink
    if(!ink.height() && !ink.width())
    {
        //use parent's width or height whichever is larger for the diameter to make a circle which can cover the entire element.
        d = Math.max(parent.outerWidth(), parent.outerHeight());
        ink.css({height: d, width: d});
    }

    //get click coordinates
    //logic = click coordinates relative to page - parent's position relative to page - half of self height/width to make it controllable from the center;
    x = e.pageX - parent.offset().left - ink.width()/2;
    y = e.pageY - parent.offset().top - ink.height()/2;

    //set the position and add class .animate
    ink.css({top: y+'px', left: x+'px'}).addClass("animate");
})
```

Comment: put that code in a directive

Comment: I face the exact same problem, but on a form element. 

Anyway, Juggling with every possibilities and coming back here with an answer. See you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Problem:* **$("ul li a")** is trying to assign click event handler *before* **main.html** getting injected into the DOM tree!

*Short solution:* (edit one line)
in **ripple.js**

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li a', function (e) {
```

*Better solution* (more control):

In **ripple.js** put all code into a new function like:

```
function add_ripple_btn_effect()
    //jQuery time
    var parent, ink, d, x, y;
    $("ul li a").click(function(e){
    ...
    ...
}
```

then call this function in [UI stateChange success event](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).
This method will allow you to add more jQuery codes in future and disable/enable them easily.