# JavaScript not accessible outside the ui-view

Tags: html, angularjs

I have been trying to fix a problem that was previously discarded by someone with a similar problem on stack overflow at this link: [Previous Problem and attempted solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995949/javascript-not-accessible-from-inside-angular-ui-view)

**I have up loaded the full project solution on Github at this address:** [Project](https://github.com/Gert25/CustomCraft.git)

**Problem Description:**

When the index.html file loads the home.html located in the partials/home.html via AngularJS ui router's ui-view directive, the expected display seems to break which is caused by the home.html not able to access the javascript reference needed to render the display correctly.

**Detail Description**
In my project I have attempted to create a SPA using AngularJS. My main landing page is the index.html that contains the ui-view directive for loading partials views. The following is all my code in the index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='main'>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Links -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/camera.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/google-map.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mailform-sub.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/search.css">

<script src="bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Angular/Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-load/angular-load.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--JS-->
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/rd-smoothscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/device.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body>

<div class="page" >
<!--========================================================
                          HEADER
=========================================================-->
<header>
<div id="stuck_container" class="stuck_container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top ">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
                    
<div class="navbar-brand">
<p>Custom <span>Craft</span></p>
</div>
                   
</div>
<ul class="navbar-nav sf-menu navbar-right" data-type="navbar">
<li class="active">
<a href="./">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a ui-sref='home'>About</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="#">Aliuam congu </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Ferentum nisl </a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Mauris accan </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="#">Aliuam congu</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Ferentum nisl</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Mauris accan </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Nullavel diam</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Nullavel diam</a>
</li>

</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="index-2.html">Services</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="index-3.html">Projects</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="index-4.html">Contacts</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>

  
</div>

<section class="camera_container">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="head">
           
                </p>

                <p class="ins1">
                 
                </p>
           
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="camera" class="camera_wrap">
<div data-src="images/Home1a.jpg">
<div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

</div>
</div>
<div data-src="images/Home2.jpg">
<div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

                </div>
            </div>
<div data-src="images/Home3.jpg">
<div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</header>
 
<!--View-->
<div ui-view></div>
<!--========================================================
                        FOOTER
=========================================================-->
<footer ng-controller="mainController">

<section class="well_foot-1 bg1">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

               <h4>about us</h4>

               <p>
                  We specialize in new developments and the construction of new homes. 
                  <br/>
                  We also specialize in alterations, additions and steel constructions.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                   
               </p>
           </div>
         

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 clear-md">
               <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                     
                  <div>
                      <span> <img src="images/Icons/Phone.png" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; padding-right: 5px"  alt="Phone"/></span>
                       +27 72 996 9137
                  </div>
                
               <div>
                   <span> <img src="images/Icons/Message Filled.png" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; padding-right: 5px"  alt="Message"/> </span>
                       <a href="#" >Send us a Message</a>
                
               </div>

            </div>

           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <h4>
                   Follow us
               </h4>
               <ul class="link-list">
                   <li>
                       <a href="https://www.instagram.com/custom_craft/">
                           <span>
                                <img src="images/Icons/Instagram-50.png" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-right: 5px"  alt="Custom Craft Instagram"/>
                           </span>
                          
                           Instagram
                       </a>
                   </li>
                  
                   <li>
                       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/customcraftcon">
                           <span>
                               <img src="images/Facebook-50.png" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-right: 5px" alt="Custom Craft Facebook"/>
                           </span>
                           Facebook
                       </a>
                   </li>
            
               </ul>
           </div>

       </div>
   </div>
</section>   



    <section  class="well_foot-2">
        <div class="container">
          
                <!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <h1>Custom <span style="color:#0531F7">Craft</span> <span style="color: black; font-size: 16px">(Pty)&nbsp; Ltd &nbsp; &copy {{Year}}</span>  </h1> 
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="images/Logo.jpg" style="width: 200px ; height: 200px" alt="Custome Craft Logo"/>
                        
                </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</footer>
</div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as     needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tm-scripts.js"></script>
<!-- </script> -->


</body>
</html>
```

The following snippet shows the angular code in the js/Angular/Main.js folder which configures the route options.

```
var app  = angular.module("main", ["ui.router", "angularLoad"]);
app.run(function(angularLoad,$rootScope, $urlRouter){
 
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function(evt){

      
    
});


});
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
  
$stateProvider.state("home", {
      
       url: "/home",
       templateUrl: "partails/home.html"
     
  });
 
});

app.controller("mainController" , ["$scope", 
function($scope){
   
    var year  = new Date();
    $scope.Year  = year.getFullYear();
 
}]);
```

Next is the partial view that the ui-view loads when the index.html is loaded for the first time that is located at partials/home.html.

```
<main>     

<!--========================================================
                          CONTENT
=========================================================-->
<section class="well well1">
        <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wow fadeInLeft" data- wow-delay=".9s">

                   
                    <img src="images/BigIcon/icon-58111.png" alt="Project Management"/>
                    <h5 class="ins_r">
                        Project
                        Management
                    </h5>

                    <p class="txt-light">
                        With more than a decade of experience in the construction industry 
                        you can rest assured that your construction venture will yield the best
                        possible outcome for your money. We plan ahead, to avoid disastrous situations 
                        and misfortune, and take responsibility to insure that our projects stays on schedule 
                        and on budget.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".7s">

                    <img src="images/BigIcon/icon-28433.png" alt="Building Innovation"/>
                    <h5 class="ins_r">
                        Building
                        Innovation
                    </h5>
                            
                    <p class="txt-light">
                         We push our boundaries to get you the best possible outcome. We are an evolving business
                         that strives on new ideas and the challenges that comes with it. We believe in our customers
                         visions and we design, plan and build accordingly. 
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">

                    <img src="images/BigIcon/icon-79595.png" alt="Design and Implementations"/>
                    <h5 class="ins_r">
                        Design
                        & Implementation
                    </h5>
                    
                    <p class="txt-light">
                        We are well advised from our engineers to ensure coordinated implementation and
                        show an overall commitment to make design a reality. We continuously revise our
                        strategies to adapt to the unique challenges faced during execution of each project.
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <img src="images/BigIcon/icon-99769.png" alt="Customer Satisfaction"/>
                
                    <h5 class="ins_r">
                        Customer Satisfaction
                    </h5>

                    <p class="txt-light">
                        The longevity of our company remains with our customer's satisfaction. We know how stressful
                        a construction project can be and therefore we work hard to secure your investment. We construct
                        and maintain customer relationships by providing reliable, affordable and ethical services. 
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="well well2 parallax text-center" data-  url="images/parallax1.jpg" data-mobile="true"
             data-speed="0.6">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="fw-l">
               <br/>
               
            </h2>

            <p class="white ins1 offs1">
               <!--Anticipated white text unused-->
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="ang_block bg-primary text-center wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.5s">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

                    <em>
                        43
                    </em>

                    <p>
                        clients
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

                    <em>
                        50
                    </em>

                    <p>
                        projects completed
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

                    <em>
                        113
                    </em>

                    <p>
                        Months
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

                    <em>
                        99
                    </em>

                    <p>
                       %Client Satisfaction
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <!--Services-->
    <section class="well well3">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="text-center">
                Our Services
            </h3>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".7s">
                    <div class="thumbnail thumbnail4">
                        <img src="images/architecture.jpg" alt="">

                        <div class="caption">
                            <h6>
                               Budget Planning & Architectural Design
                            </h6>

                            <p>
                               We consult with our clients to help them build their
                               projects from the ground up. We assist our clients in 
                               planning for their budget to ensure that their investments
                               reach its full potential. We supply well documented and professionally  
                               architectural designs to help are clients envision their dream.  
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-link">
                                <span class="fst" data-txt="Read More"></span>
                                <span class="snd" data-txt="Read More"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                    <div class="thumbnail thumbnail4">
                        <img src="images/renovation.jpg" alt="Renovations">

                        <div class="caption">
                            <h6>
                                Building Renovation
                            </h6>

                            <p>
                                We specialize in building renovations. We provide
                                a wide variety of alterations from painting to tilling as well as structural 
                                additions to your current building infrastructure. 
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-link">
                                <span class="fst" data-txt="Read More"></span>
                                <span class="snd" data-txt="Read More"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                    <div class="thumbnail thumbnail4">
                        <img src="images/steel.jpg" alt="Steel Constructions">

                        <div class="caption">
                            <h6>
                               Steel Constructions
                            </h6>

                            <p>
                              We have a broad number of skills and expertise to meet your 
                              your requirements. We take on various steel projects of any 
                              size and ensure that we deliver on your expectations.
                              
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn-link">
                                <span class="fst" data-txt="Read More"></span>
                                <span class="snd" data-txt="Read More"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Image 2-->
    <section class="well well4 parallax text-center" data-url="images/parallax2.jpg" data-mobile="true"
             data-speed="0.6">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>
                <!--Title--><br/>
                
            </h2>

            <p class="white ins1">
              
            </p>
          
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Why Choose Us-->
    <section class="well well5">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="text-center">
                Why Choose Us?
            </h3>

            <p class="text-center lead">
               Doing business in a competitive industry requires professional expertise and workmanship, therefore
               we would like to point out why our clients choose us above our competitors.
            </p>

            <div class="row">

                <ul class="icon-list wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s">
                  
                    <!--Dependability-->
                    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <h6>
                            <a href="#">
                                Dependability 
                            </a>
                        </h6>

                        <p>
                            We do what we say, and deliver on our promises. It is important
                            to us that we can win over our clients trust and work hard to maintain
                            their loyalty.
                        </p>
                    </li>
                   <!--Affordability-->
                    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <h6>
                            <a href="#">
                          Affordability
                            </a>
                        </h6>

                        <p>
                            By continuous collaboration with suppliers to cut 
                            cost on all material expenditures to ensure that our clients 
                            gets the best price for quality products.
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <!--Satisfying Result--->
                    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <h6>
                            <a href="#">
                                Satisfying Results
                            </a>
                        </h6>

                        <p>
                           We work hard to ensure implementation meets the design and 
                           that our projects stay on schedule. Customer satisfaction remains 
                           our priority.
                           
                       
                           
                        </p>
                    </li>
                   <!--Punctuality-->
                    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <h6>
                            <a href="#">
                               Punctuality 
                            </a>
                        </h6>

                        <p>
                           It is important to us to remain punctual to stay on track of schedules. Therefore
                           our planning oversees our challenges and that is how we remain competitive and reliable. 
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <!---Passion-->
                    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <h6>
                            <a href="#">
                               Passionate
                            </a>
                        </h6>

                        <p>
                            Our overall passion in developing and constructing buildings 
                            is the force that drives our business to strive in being extraordinary.
                            
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <h6>
                            <a href="#">
                               Cohesiveness
                            </a>
                        </h6>
                                We have a united and motivated workforce that have one clear
                                objective...to tend to our client's every need. We do not compromise
                                on the quality of service delivered to our clients.
                                
                        <p>
                          
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

      <section class="well well4 parallax text-center" data-url="images/parallax3.jpg" data-mobile="true"
             data-speed="0.6">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>
                <!--Title--><br/>
                
            </h2>

            <p class="white ins1">
              
            </p>
          
        </div>
    </section>
   <!-- <div class="map">
        <div id="google-map" class="map_model"></div>
        <ul class="map_locations">
            <li data-x="-73.9874068" data-y="40.643180">
                <p> 9870 St Vincent Place, Glasgow, DC 45 Fr 45. <span>800 2345-6789</span></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>-->

</main>
```

The following shows the image of the error I encounter when I run it
in the chrome browser

[Image: Error Produced by the Google Chrome Debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5caTE.png)

**Summary:**
The home.html view is not loaded correctly by the ui-view, as it seems that it is not able to reference the javascript files that is contained in the index.html  to render the display correctly.

**Note**
When I replace the ui-view directive in the index.html with the html markup in the home.html then everything appears to be working correctly. there is no errors what so ever.

Comment: Please reproduce a minimal example ***here*** that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Nobody is going to sift through a repo trying to find code for an issue that isn't even well defined. Include relevant code in the question and provide a much better explanation of problem along with error status from browser dev tools

Comment: I have given a complete overview of my problem. So the question again is why can't the partial view (home.html) gain proper reference to the javascript files included in the index.html

Comment: The problem at hand IS NOT a code error! Actually no need to post the code because it works fine. The problem happens at run time, when the partial View (home.html) is loaded in the parent view (index.html) via the AngularJS UI Router, which it does, but the display of the partial view is not rendered correctly because for some reason it is not able to access the full javascript reference. Hence I felt the need to post the code on Github so someone can pull into their browser, I did not expect any to go snif throught it to try and find my problem for me.

Comment: I am going to research it further and will give you guys an update If I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is the `wow.js` `init()` loaded inside `tm-scripts.js`

Try to put inside state change event with `sync()` method

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $urlRouter){
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(evt){
        console.log("test....");
        new WOW().sync();
    });
});
```